# Adding Items to a Combobox in a DataGridView in a specific row

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I was wondering if one of you guys would happen to know how to achieve what i described in the Title!?
This is what i've tried so far:

```
List<String> projects = new List<String>();
projects.Add("Hi");
DataGridViewComboBoxCell dropDown = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)userTable.Rows[1].Cells[2];
//1st Row | 3rd Column
dropDown.DataSource = projects;
this.userTable.Rows.Add("", "", dropDown, "");
```

userTable is my DataGridView with 4 Columns. The one with the Combobox is the 3rd on, so it has the Index 2.
Sadly this doesn't work and i don't know why, so any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT 1:
Whole code:

```
int rows = 0;
using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = MySQL.iniHandle())
{
    using (MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        if (!MySQL.open(mySqlConnection))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`";
            rows = Convert.ToInt32(mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
            using (MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (mySqlDataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
                            {
                                int Id = (int)mySqlDataReader["Id"];
                                string Username = (string)mySqlDataReader["Username"];
                                string CPU = (string)mySqlDataReader["CPU"];
                                string LastIP = (string)mySqlDataReader["LastIP"];
                                string ProjectName = "";
                                string ProjectStatus = "";

                                using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection1 = MySQL.iniHandle())
                                {
                                    if (!MySQL.open(mySqlConnection1))
                                    {
                                        return -1;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        using (MySqlCommand mySqlCommand1 = mySqlConnection1.CreateCommand())
                                        {
                                            mySqlCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `authing` WHERE UserId=@IDD";
                                            mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDD", Id);
                                            int rows1 = Convert.ToInt32(mySqlCommand1.ExecuteScalar());
                                            mySqlCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `authing` WHERE UserId=@ID";
                                            mySqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Id);
                                            List<String> projects = new List<String>();

                                            using (MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader1 = mySqlCommand1.ExecuteReader())
                                            {
                                                if (mySqlDataReader1.HasRows)
                                                {
                                                    try
                                                    {
                                                        while (mySqlDataReader1.Read())
                                                        {
                                                            for (int j = 0; j < rows1; j++)
                                                            {
                                                                int ProjectId = (int)mySqlDataReader1["ProjectId"];
                                                                ProjectStatus = getProjectStatus((int)mySqlDataReader1["Status"]);

                                                                using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection2 = MySQL.iniHandle())
                                                                {
                                                                    if (!MySQL.open(mySqlConnection2))
                                                                    {
                                                                        return -1;
                                                                    }
                                                                    else
                                                                    {
                                                                        using (MySqlCommand mySqlCommand2 = mySqlConnection2.CreateCommand())
                                                                        {
                                                                            mySqlCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE Id=@ProjectID";
                                                                            mySqlCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ProjectId);

                                                                            using (MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader2 = mySqlCommand2.ExecuteReader())
                                                                            {
                                                                                if (mySqlDataReader2.HasRows)
                                                                                {
                                                                                    try
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        while (mySqlDataReader2.Read())
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            ProjectName = (string)mySqlDataReader2["Name"];
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    catch (MySqlException excp)
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        return -2;
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                            projects.Add(ProjectName + " => " + ProjectStatus);
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            try
                                                            {
                                                                DataGridViewComboBoxCell dropDown = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)userTable.Rows[i].Cells[2];
                                                                dropDown.DataSource = projects;
                                                                dropDown.ValueType = typeof(string);
                                                                this.userTable.Rows.Add(Username, CPU, dropDown, LastIP);
                                                            }
                                                            catch(Exception e)
                                                            {
                                                                this.logServerActivity(e.ToString());
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                catch (MySqlException excp)
                                                {
                                                    return -2;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (MySqlException excp)
                {
                    return -2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
mySqlConnection.Close();
}
return rows;
```

As you can see I'm reading User Data in from a MySQL-Database, then i create a new Row with this Data and in this row, there should be a cloumn with a Combobox, which contains all the Projects the user is Authed for and the Status after a "=>". MySQL Code is fine, just the setting in Combobox Part is difficult and sorry for the long Code!

Comment: Do you get an exception? What is the wrong behavior?

Comment: @OfirW System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event

Comment: Where exactly do you get it, and why do you try to have a different source at `row[1]` ? the comboBoxSource is bounded to the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

Comment: Also what was the source before?

Comment: @OfirW before it didnt had a source... I get it as soon as i try to click on the Combobox in the Datagridview. I want to have different items in the comboboxes per row

Comment: Try this: `dropDown.ValueType = typeof(string);`

Comment: @OfirW sadly it didn't worked :( I provided my whole code and it's purpose in the OP, so maybe you can understand better what my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell dropDown = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)userTable.Rows[i].Cells[2];
```

you must use this:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dropDown = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
```

you can remove that `try` block (temporarily) to debug your code better.
also check if `this.userTable.Rows.Add(Username, CPU, dropDown, LastIP);` can add also `Controls` not only values..

Comment: This: DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dropDown = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                                                                            dropDown.DataSource = projects;
                                                                            dropDown.ValueType = typeof(string);
                                                                            this.userTable.Rows.Add(Username, CPU, dropDown, LastIP); doesn't work, any other suggestions!? Also Rows.Add() taks a obj Array

Comment: did you remove the `try-catch` and debug the code to see what happens when you run that `userTable.Rows.Add`?

Comment: i did and it doesnt show a error anymore, but the combobox just has no contents now...

Answer (score 0):

First, Your `ArgumentException` is because you cannot add a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` with this: `this.userTable.Rows.Add(Username, CPU, dropDown, LastIP);`
Because the `Add` Method receive values not `Cells` and your `dropDown` is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`

Second, I don't see why you're trying to add records the the grid. 
You've already changed the ComboBox's `DataSource` in the specific row. There's no reason to add it again.

If you *do* try to add rows after all, then add the row first and then alter it's combobox datasource.